# How can I make a line follow a path animated object in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

I am trying to make a fairly simple animation in PowerPoint. Boiling it down to its essential parts, I have two boxes joined by a line. I want to use a path animation to move one of the boxes. At the same time, I want to ensure that the line keeps joining the two boxes during and after the path animation. This picture shows what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: Before-and-after image]

I have anchored the line to the sides of both boxes so that it follows either box around as I click and drag it. However, during a path animation, the line does not follow the animated box.

As a less convenient workaround, I tried to see if it was possible to make a corresponding path animation for the line, so that its right end follows the box as it moves. However, I cannot find any way to animate just one of the ends of the line instead of having the whole line move.

Is this kind of animation possible to achieve in PowerPoint? In case it is relevant, I am using PowerPoint 2016 for Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to achieve the same effect without using a path animation. In PowerPoint 2016 and 2019 for Windows and PowerPoint 2019 for Mac, you can use [morph transitions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-morph-transition-in-powerpoint-8dd1c7b2-b935-44f5-a74c-741d8d9244ea) between two slides. To achieve what the question's image shows, you need to:

- Create a slide with the original layout (two boxes joined by a line)
- Duplicate the slide
- Go to the duplicated slide and drag the right-hand box to where you want it
- From the Transitions ribbon, apply the Morph transition to the duplicated slide

With this, the line follows the box as it smoothly moves between its positions as we transition from one slide to the next.

Unfortunately, I cannot use this myself as it is not supported in PowerPoint 2016 for Mac, but I have at least been able to verify that it works in PowerPoint 2016 for Windows.